# Python: Como hago para detener el bucle por un numero negativo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Verán les cuento, quería ahcer una pelea sencilla para una asignacion escolar.

Logré que cuando el primer ataque del usuario se use repetidamente sobre el enemigo, al llegar la vida de este a '0' se detiene

Posteriormente intenté hacerlo con el segundo ataque era mas fuerte, y coloque el fin del bucle, era cuando el valor de 'hp' fuera menor o igual que cero (enemyhp <= 0)

Estoy utilizando un bucle While True, y utilizo Continue para repetir todo el proceso, mi duda es, que cuando se utiliza solo el segundo ataque, el hp del enemigo pasa a ser -numero(ej -20)

y el bucle no se cierra y no muetra el mensaje de "Haz derrotado al enemigo", si no que continua

Acá le muestro el código que llevo escrito:

```
enemyhp = 100
enemydef = 20

userhp = 100
userdef = 20
dañomano = 40
dañopalo = 60
while True: # Bucle infinito Verdadero

    print("Un enemigo ha aparecido, no tienes otra opcion que luchar!")
    print("Que deseas hacer?: ")
    print("A. Pegarle con la mano\t B. Pegarle con un palo\t C. Defenderte")
    print(f"Vida del enemigo actualmente {enemyhp}")

    useratk = input("------>   ").lower()
    if enemyhp!=0:
        if useratk=='a':
            perdida = dañomano - enemydef
            enemyhp = enemyhp - perdida
            print(f"Le haz pegado con la mano, y le haz quitado {perdida}")
            print(f"El enemigo le queda {enemyhp} de hp")
            print()
            print()

        if useratk=='b':
            perdida = dañopalo - enemydef
            enemyhp = enemyhp - perdida
            print(f"Le haz pegado con un palo, y le haz quitado {perdida}")
            print(f"El enemigo le queda {(enemyhp)} de hp")
            print()
            print()

        continue

    if enemyhp<=0:
        print()
        print("Haz derrotado al enemigo")
        break
```

Por ejemplo si corren ese codigo, y utilizan 3 veces la opcion 'b' llegados a un punto el valor del enemyhp sera '-20', y el bucle no se cierra y sigue avanzando como si nada.

PD:
La version de python es: 3.9
Uso windows 10 64 bits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

¡Bienvenido y felicidades por tu juego! Está muy interesante, me gustó la narrativa. El problema que tienes está en el `continue` que hace que salte a la siguiente iteración del bucle `while` de una vez, sin pasar por la condicional `if enemyhp<=0:`.

Si leemos la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html):

> The continue statement, also borrowed from C, continues with the next
> iteration of the loop.

Traducción:

> La declaración continue, tomada prestada de C, continua con la
> siguiente iteración del bucle

Comment: ho, tenias razon, ese era el problema xD, solo lo tuve que mover de lugar y me funciono, grax <3

Comment: ¡Con gusto! Espero que el juego sea un éxito, si te fue útil por favor marca la respuesta como acertada, para que todo otro usuario que tenga el mismo problema que tú pueda encontrar la respuesta en el sitio.

Answer (score 1):

mi contribucion, me he tomado el atrevimiento de organizarte las salidas del juego, saludos

```
enemyhp = 100
enemydef = 20
userhp = 100
userdef = 20
dañomano = 40
dañopalo = 60
while enemyhp>0: # Bucle infinito Verdadero
    print("Un enemigo ha aparecido, no tienes otra opcion que luchar!")
    print("Que deseas hacer?: ")
    print("A. Pegarle con la mano\t B. Pegarle con un palo\t C. Defenderte")
    print(f"Vida del enemigo actualmente {enemyhp}")
    useratk = input("------>   ").lower()
    if useratk=='a':
        perdida = dañomano - enemydef
        enemyhp = enemyhp - perdida
        print(f"Le haz pegado con la mano, y le haz quitado {perdida}")
        if enemyhp>=0:
            print(f"El enemigo le queda {enemyhp} de hp")
            print()
            print()

    if useratk=='b':
        perdida = dañopalo - enemydef
        enemyhp = enemyhp - perdida
        print(f"Le haz pegado con un palo, y le haz quitado {perdida}")
        if enemyhp>=0:
            print(f"El enemigo le queda {enemyhp} de hp")
            print()
            print()
else:
    print("Haz derrotado al enemigo")
```